# how get link on first image from several images?

Tags: php

I have code:

```
$images = '
<img src="./243234345/Desert1.jpg" alt="" width="1024" height="768" />
<img src="./243234345/Desert2.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="100" />
<img src="./243234345/Desert3.jpg" alt="" width="500" height="120" />
<img src="./243234345/Desert4.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="50" />
';
```

Tell me please how get link on first image?

Comment: i think your best option is using explode function of php.explode using some separator and than fetch the first array index from the array.

Comment: @RishabhRaj sure i can use several explode, ex. first $arr = explode('<img',$images); $first_img = '<img'.$arr[1]; but i think exist other answer(may be).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like using some delimiter like `,`

```
$images = '
<img src="./243234345/Desert1.jpg" alt="" width="1024" height="768" />
<img src="./243234345/Desert2.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="100" />
<img src="./243234345/Desert3.jpg" alt="" width="500" height="120" />
<img src="./243234345/Desert4.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="50" />
';

$imagesArray = explode('/>',trim($images)); 

$FirstImage =  $imagesArray[0];// display first image

$FirstImage =  $FirstImage .'/>';

preg_match( '@src="([^"]+)"@' , $FirstImage , $matchData );

print_r($matchData);
```

You can try this one : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: ya this is what i meant in my comment above :)

Comment: but not good - becose it answer use symbol `,` - that not use in code question.
for example you can see my comment with `explode`. but me need link on image..

Comment: Updated answer, can you try

Comment: i can not add symbold in code- i can not add symbol `,` becose i get i html from `post`

Comment: I have used to  explode('/>'). Is it ok ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to do this.

```
$images = '
<img src="./243234345/Desert1.jpg" alt="" width="1024" height="768" />,
<img src="./243234345/Desert2.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="100" />,
<img src="./243234345/Desert3.jpg" alt="" width="500" height="120" />,
<img src="./243234345/Desert4.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="50" />
';
$matches = array();
preg_match('/<img\s*src\s*=\s*[\'"]([^\'"]*)[\'"]/',$images,$matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: i can not add symbold in code- i can not add symbol `,` becose i get i html from `post`